# Proving convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\frac\pi2-\arctan n}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am interested in this sum for an integral

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\frac\pi2-\arctan n}{n}$$

It seems to converge from the graph of partial sums, but I don’t know how to formally prove it. I am also interested in the answer too

I started by converting the numerator into an integral realizing $\pi/2$ is just $\arctan(nx)$ evaluated at $x=\infty$, switched the integral with the sum, and got the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

You can apply the following relations in order to check convergence:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(n) = \arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) < \frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}

More precisely, one has the next situation:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\pi/2 - \arctan(n)}{n} & = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n} < \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^{2}}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan n = \int_n^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} \le \int_n^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2}$$

Can you derive the convergence from this?